# Failed to start iptables-persistent.service

Tags: iptables

**Ubuntu 16.04.2**

In a book I read that we need iptables-persistent. 
The book was published in 2016.

Ok:

```
sudo apt install -y iptables-persistent
```

Everything installed. No problems so far. If I reboot the computer, iptables is still here.

Then in the book I read:

```
sudo service iptables-persistent start.
```

And I get this:

```
Failed to start iptables-persistent.service: Unit iptables-persistent.service not found.
```

Could you comment: is it acceptable behavior for Ubuntu 16.04.2?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems since Ubuntu 16.04, iptables-persistent has been replaced by netfilter-persistent. The package still exist and automatically install netfilter-persistent thanks to a dependancy. It's possible to use the following command to start the firewall.

```
sudo service netfilter-persistent start
```